# Kotlin JS: Generate wrapper from index.d.ts

Tags: node.js, express, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm looking into using Kotlin JS for an express app. I realized that there isn't a complete, up-to-date wrapper for express, but the package has the types defined in its `index.d.ts` file. Is there a way to use that to generate my wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is something like [types-kotlin](https://github.com/karakum-team/types-kotlin) lib.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. I found another repo with similar content, but not this one. Unfortunately, it doesn't have types for express, which is what I'm looking for. I tried using their tools to generate it myself, but it is really complicated and time-consuming